# Trying to Make an Commands Page to List all the commands on my discord bot but idk how

Tags: html, css, command, discord

I am trying to figure out how to make a commands page for my discord bot's website. I want the commands page to look and work something like this https://amaribot.com/commands but i just for the love of God cant figure it out! Can anyone help me or provide some code/recommendations to help :3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to use the Bootstrap collapsible accordion

here is an example :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">

  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
          1st ITEM
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Some text inside the 1st item
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
        Item #2
      </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          some more text inside this one
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree">
          another one #3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          some text to be shown here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i wish it can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are very helpful this will definingly help me